# Add new viewcontroller at launch of app IOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, webview

I am new to IOS development . i got a open source project and loaded in xcode and it is running good.

the project is based on webview and loading url.

what i want to do is add a new screen at the launch of application which takes three inputs from textfields and on submit of button it should send the data to next screen which is a webview and currently it is being loaded first .

1) how can i add new view controller which launches first at launch of app where i can input textfields and click on button to move to second screen

2) get the data from first screen and give to the load url to load the url.

i have taken project files from here :

https://github.com/paulirish/iOS-WebView-App

[image]

viewcontroller option on right side doesnt have the option is initial view 
i am using xcode 6.2

Comment: What you are effectively asking here, is how to develop an app. This is an incredibly broad question that is off-topic for stackoverflow. You need to do some research, read an iOS book, follow tutorials and learn more about the platform. Otherwise you will be reliant on the community to develop your app for you. The information you seek is freely availble online, in many many many different sources. Stackoverflow is meant for specific issues or debugging errors, not asking developers to do your work for you.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right . i have researched alot . where i am stuck is i have a webview project which loads url . i want to add a new view at startup  with text field and whato ever url i enter should load it in the next view thats it . but when created new view edited all the .xib file now how to attach this particular view at launch ?????

Comment: yes, you basically repeated your question. I did in fact read it the first time. That doesn't change anything. There are many many tutorials online showing how to set the first viewController that loads, its the first step in any iPhone devleopment. The fact that its a webview bares no difference. You need to study more about iOS and how to create apps. I suggest downloading a professional book / taking a free course rather than skimming tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are loading viewcontroller from code like we did in older versions. I hope this helps you.

In this code you can simply change MainViewController to your own view.

```
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

`MainViewController* viewC =[[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController* navC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewC];
self.window.rootViewController = navC;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`

Comment: Wonderfull you got me where i was stuck ... it worked .. thanx a lot , now i can move and start learning ahead . thanks man..... cheers

Comment: @Addi.Star great all the very best :)

Comment: can you provide any good tutorials which are following this old versions styles of coding so that i can learn more comprehensively

Comment: @Addi.Star I would suggest start learning storyboard as it will help you, you can also watch www.surbhigarg.com for small tutorials. I am writting these

Comment: i want to ask one more thing can u talk in chat or where i can share my problem aside from this forum

Comment: @Addi.Star sure I will reply you on my portal, give me 4 hours will catch u in evening. Happy to help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118925/discussion-between-surbhi-garg-and-addi-star).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to **create new UIViewController** with your three textFields and then **set this  UIViewController as Initial View Controller** from storyboard like this:

[image]

After doing this get data from your textfields like:

```
NSString *text1Data = self.yourtextField.text;//Repeat for all text fields.
```

After getting data make three variables in your webViewController and assign thse values to them.

Suppose WebVC is yoour WebViewController then you can pass data and go to web viw like this:

```
WebVC *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"your_WebVc_identifier"];
vc.text1DataFromFirstVC = text1Data; //repeat for all three variables

//go to web view controller
[self.navigationController pushViewController: vc animated:YES]
```

**EDIT:For Non Storyboard use following code from your `AppDelegate`**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    ViewController *Vc = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = Vc;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: my project has no story board . i have created three new files.   1)sencndViewcontroller.h 2)sencndViewcontroller.m 3)sencndViewcontroller.xib

Comment: i have these three new file. how can i existing project to launch these file firs then i will put text fields and get data from it and pass to webview class which is currently loading at launch

Comment: check my uploaded image as u can see my files in xcode and no option for setting initial view

Comment: Bro you really need to go for basics first. I have given you just an example, you will have to use your ViewController object instead my mine.

Comment: i told you i am totally new to ios development